# About UIImageView+MKNetworkKitAdditions

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mknetworkkit

I use UIImageView+MKNetworkKitAdditions in MKNetworkKit to show image from network, but when the UIImageView is in the tableView Cell, the method

```
-(MKNetworkOperation*) setImageFromURL:(NSURL*) url 
                      placeHolderImage:(UIImage*) image 
                             animation:(BOOL) yesOrNo;
```

won't show the image immediately after the image is downloaded. If I use

```
[tableView reloadData]
```

I won't see the animation of showing image.
So I'm wondering how I can solve this problem.
Thank you.

My codes are here

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
[cell.imageView setImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"]];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: you should show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `UITableViewCell` has very optimised drawing and when this method is called there is no image in the imageView so the cell assumes that it is not required to render an image.

Now when the network request completes it will set the image but it is not asking the cell to redraw so you will see nothing.

You need to use a method that has a completion block and then ask the cell to reload when the image request has completed.

Comment: I have tried the method  reloadRowsAtIndexPaths  and it will lead to a reload cycle. I have found that because of there is no image before network request completes so the size of imageView is (0,0). And I use the   layoutSubviews after network request completes to solve this problem. Thanks a lot!